# Isolation Forest in Python

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, outliers, anomaly-detection

I am currently working on detecting outliers in my dataset using [Isolation Forest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html) in Python and I did not completely understand the example and explanation given in scikit-learn documentation

Is it possible to use Isolation Forest to detect outliers in my dataset that has 258 rows and 10 columns?

Do I need a separate dataset to train the model? If yes, is it necessary to have that training dataset free from outliers?

This is my code:

```
rng = np.random.RandomState(42)
X = 0.3*rng.randn(100,2)
X_train = np.r_[X+2,X-2]
clf = IsolationForest(max_samples=100, random_state=rng, contamination='auto'
clf.fit(X_train)
y_pred_train = clf.predict(x_train)
y_pred_test = clf.predict(x_test)
print(len(y_pred_train))
```

I tried by loading my dataset to `X_train` but that does not seem to work.

Comment: Your code is working for your toy example with minor corrections. If you have problems with running `IsolationForest` on your dataset show it to us with all the preprocessing steps you've done and error message that you have

Comment: Do you have ground truth labels for your "outliers"?

Comment: @davidrpugh You do not need any "ground truth" for `IsolationForest`, the rationale behind it is different...

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov I understand that ground truth labels are not needed in order to use `IsolationForest` however if OP has such labels, then you could use this information to tune hyperparameters or score `IsolationForest` on test data for comparison with other models.

Answer (score 9):

> Do I need a separate dataset to train the model?

Short answer is "No". You train and predict outliers on the same data.

`IsolationForest` is an unsupervised learning algorithm that's intended to clean your data from outliers (see [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html) for more). In usual machine learning settings, you would run it to clean your training dataset. As far as your toy example concerned:

```
rng = np.random.RandomState(42)
X = 0.3*rng.randn(100,2)
X_train = np.r_[X+2,X-2]

from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
clf = IsolationForest(max_samples=100, random_state=rng, behaviour="new", contamination=.1)

clf.fit(X_train)
y_pred_train = clf.predict(X_train)
y_pred_train
array([ 1,  1,  1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
        1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
        1,  1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
        1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
        1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
        1,  1,  1,  1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
        1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
        1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
        1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
       -1,  1,  1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
        1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
        1,  1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1])
```

where `1` represent inliers and `-1` represent outliers. As specified by `contamination` param, the fraction of outliers is `0.1`.

Finally, you would remove outliers like:

```
X_train_cleaned = X_train[np.where(y_pred_train == 1, True, False)]
```