# Outlier removal Isolation Forest

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook, random-forest

I've been trying to remove outliers from my database using isolation forest, but I can't figure out how. I've seen the examples for credit card fraud and Salary but I can't figure out how to apply them on each column as my database consists of 3862900 rows and 19 columns. I've uploaded an image of the head of my database. I can't figure out how to apply isolation forest on each column then permanently remove these outliers.[image]

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html) is used for detecting outliers not removing them

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'temp': [1,2,3,345,6,7,5345, 8, 9, 10, 11]})
clf = IsolationForest().fit(df['temp'].values.reshape(-1, 1)) 
clf.predict([[4], [5], [3636]])
```

`array([ 1,  1, -1])`

As you can see from the output `4` and `5` are not outliers but 3636 is.

If you want to remove outliers from your dataframe you should use the IQR

```
quant = df['temp'].quantile([0.25, 0.75])
df['temp'][~df['temp'].clip(*quant).isin(quant)]
```

```
4     6
5     7
7     8
8     9
9    10
```

As you can see the outliers have been removed

For the whole df

```
def IQR(df, colname, bounds = [.25, .75]):
    s = df[colname]
    q = s.quantile(bounds)
    return df[~s.clip(*q).isin(q)]
```

Note: Isolation forest cannot remove outliers from your dataset, it is used to detect new outliers

Comment: is it possible to remove the outliers with IQR for example using the results of the isolation forest predictions?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, the results of isolation forest are values that are not in your original dataset, so their already removed.

Comment: My dataset is full of outliers, isolation forest can’t detect these outliers?

Comment: isolation forest is for detecting if a value (OUTSIDE your dataset) is an outlier. If you dataset is full of outliers and you want to remove them use the IQR. Isolation forest doesn't remove

Comment: yes my question is, can I remove them using any method based on isolation forest results?

Comment: Then the answer is no, you cannot remove with that method

Comment: I added it to the question, if that is all please accept so this question can be closed. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

`IsolationForest` **could intend** to clean your data from outliers. As it says this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54742350/10452700), *In usual machine learning settings, you would run it to clean your training dataset*.

```py
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
clf = IsolationForest(max_samples=100, random_state=4, contamination=.1)
#identify outliers:
y_pred_train = clf.fit_predict(X_train)
#Remove outliers where 1 represent inliers and -1 represent outliers:
X_train_cleaned = X_train[np.where(y_pred_train == 1, True, False)]
```

We could use a different method like IQR to parameterization for `contamination` in the unsupervised setting.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'am late in answering this question, but as @Kenan said `Isolation forest is used to identify outliers but totally remove them`.

One thing you could do is use `O_Sieve` it performs automatic outlier removal and gives you the dataset.

```
pip install vcosmos
from spatial_domain.anaomaly import O_Sieve
sieve=O_Sieve(your_df target_column, tsf=2,tsf=2)
clean_df=sieve.filtered_data()
print(clean_df)
```

You can adjust the tsf and bsf params to chose how it affects the number of outliers.
To read more, check the documentation of [vcosmos](https://pypi.org/project/vcosmos/)